# How can I make vim recognize the file's encoding?

Tags: vim

I noticed that most of the time, when using some encoding other than 'the standard english', vim doesn't recognize and does not display characters correctly.
This is most easily seen by opening some ascii graphics, or similar files off the net, which use cp437 code page.

Is there a way to make vim check for encoding when opening a file, and open it with a correct one ?

What encodings do you use, as the most "portable" ones (the ones which the largest amount of users will have least problems with) ?

Comment: The issue you're facing doesn't have a lot to do with English, because a lot of punctuation marks used in English are missing from ASCII, such as emdashes and some currency symbols, including from some English-speaking countries. ASCII only really had US-English in mind, which isn't really 'standard', as much as USAns like to pretend it is. ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Vim needs to detect the encoding, and that's going to be problematic, since files don't often explicitly state their encodings (an obvious exception are XML files with an encoding attribute in the header).

You can force Vim to reload a file with a different encoding thus:

```
:e ++enc=cp437
```

and you can set the default encoding in your .vimrc if you wish.

[This page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode#See_also) has more info and links, especially wrt. editing Unicode. UTF-8 is the most widely-used encoding, and the default you should probably go for.

Comment: So nice to see so clever people around the world. Thanks you for such an useful answer ;)

Comment: what does mean the `++`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a vim modeline to set the file's encoding. This is simply a comment, in the first five lines of the file, that starts with `vi: set fileencoding=cp437`.

You could also start with 'vim:', instead of 'vi: set', but the latter makes it compatible with more editors. You definitely need the space between either of these prefixes and 'fileencoding', or whatever option you want to set. The `fileencoding` option should solve your problem, though.

So, in Python or an .rc file, you can put this at the top of your file:

```
# vi: set fileencoding=cp437
```

In Java, C, C++, JavaScript, etc. put this:

```
// vi: set fileencoding=cp437
```

For more information, in vim, type `:help modeline`.

Comment: Edited as suggested by user @SumnerHayes, to show that the modeline has to be one of the first five lines in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable 'fileencodings' in your .vimrc.

> This is a list of character encodings considered when starting to edit
>       an existing file.  When a file is read, Vim tries to use the first
>       mentioned character encoding.  If an error is detected, the next one
>       in the list is tried.  When an encoding is found that works,
>       'fileencoding' is set to it.  If all fail, 'fileencoding' is set to
>       an empty string, which means the value of 'encoding' is used.

See `:help filencodings`

If you often work with e.g. cp437 or cp1252, you can add it there:

```
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,cp1252,default,latin9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your files using unicode, and set a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) in the file. This will make vim treat it appropriately, but some compilers and programs may have trouble with it. Even basic shell commands like `cat` may misbehave for some use cases.

To do it, type this in vim:

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:set bomb
:w
```

For more information, type:

```
:help bomb
```

Answer (score 0):

Add at the end of your .vimrc: (you can replace "utf-8" by "latin1" if needed)

```
if len(&fenc) == 0
  silent! exe "e! ++enc=utf-8" 
endif
```